# Solid color DIV inside DIV with opacity; ONCLICK event problem

Tags: html, css, onclick, z-index, opacity

I have a parent DIV with a position: fixed; and opacity: 0.7; and inside of it I have a child DIV with a background-color: white;

[image]

How do I use a ONCLICK event that makes both the parent DIV and child DIV disappear when only clicking on the black space you see?

Since the white DIV is nested inside the parent DIV with an opacity, whenever I click the white DIV, the whole parent DIV (black opacity DIV) disappears...

I need both DIV to disappear when the black opacity is clicked... not when the white DIV is clicked...

Comment: use event.stopPropogation() to stop disappearing when child is clicked. View more https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation. Or post a reproducible example so someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem like that when i was creating a lightbox (modal) and wanting to use only 2 elements: The overlay, and the content (white box). Same structure as yours. So, here is what you can do:

On your parent you will listen to the click, check if the clicked element is exactly the parent and not one of its children, then hide it. I will apply this behavior to a class, so you just add the class on your parent element or tweak the code to fit your needings:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.hide-on-click-exact').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target === this) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
});
```

So, just add the class "hide-on-click-exact" to your parent div, and load this snippet somewhere after, and your're done. The ideia is simple: If the targeted click is exactly the ".hide-on-click-exact" element, hide it.

Note: Be careful, dont use arrow functions on the eventListener callback of this snippet, since arrow functions has no scope, the "this" will be no longer the clicked element, but the window.